# В Python не полностью распознается URL если в нем есть русские символы

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, http, curl

У меня есть строка, которую я передаю CURL

`upload_oth = f'curl -k -u login:pass -T  {filename}  "https://cloud.dit.mos.ru/remote.php/dav/files/DIT-VKS-LdapUser/Other/тест"'`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если строка с русскими буквами, то она уже не распознается как полноценная ссылка
И запрос падает с ошибкой
`Your browser sent an invalid request.`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как преобразовать сроку в полный URL и с русскими буквами

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5607551/7485582

Comment: Не в python, а в редакторе кода или IDE, которое вы используете. На работу вашей программы это никак не влияет.

Comment: Если дело не в Python, может сам запрос CURL не обработать кириллицу?

Comment: @АлексейС ещё один запрос в гугл и ещё одно решение https://stackoverflow.com/a/2027690/7485582

Comment: @АлексейС я бы сначала проверил, а потом уже при возникновении проблем разбирался. Вообще, не понятно зачем curl из Python вызывать, если есть возможность посылать запросы напрямую из Python, например через requests.

Comment: Требуется использовать стандартную библиотеку

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html

Answer (score 0):

Для корректной работы потребовалось кодировать URL. Использовал quote() функцию, предоставляемую urllib.parsepackage.quote()

```
from urllib.parse import unquote, quote

upload_oth = f'curl -k -u login:pass -T {quote(filename)} "https://cloud.dit.mos.ru/remote.php/dav/files/DIT-VKS-LdapUser/Other/{quote(filename)}
```

Вот эта статья помогла https://www.urlencoder.io/python/

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ну если urllib используете, то имеет смысл и запрос через него делать, а не через curl.